# What's involved with installing a JetDirect card for an HP Laserjet 4500?

Tags: printer, network-adapter, hp-laserjet

So I have an opportunity to pick an HP 4500 Laserjet for a pretty good price and am on the fence.  The only problem is that it currently only has a parallel connection on it.  However, the seller claims that it can accept a JetDirect upgrade card to make it network ready.  I did a bit of browsing on ebay and found quite a few of these cards available.

My question:
**What's involved with installing one of these cards and configuring them correctly?**

Comment: JetDirect (aka print server) Have a look at this page...http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=25505&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=25505&objectID=bpl08419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after installing the jetdirect card, you should:

1. connect to its web interface. the ip it takes is either static like 192.168.1.1 or dynamic.
2. configure the ip address
3. print a test page (with system status) from the webpage
4. configure the printer at you workstation
5. print a test page
6. profit!

6(optional). firmware upgrade if it provides anything useful

hope it helps,
M

Answer (score 2):

Which model of JetDirect are you looking at for your printer?

[See this page for General instructions](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=25505&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=25505&objectID=bpl08419#A1)

[More extensive documentation here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00681848&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en)

[Firmware upgrades for the JetDirect print server](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=bpj07429)